# javascript related warnings/errors on apache

Tags: javascript, html, apache

I have a small piece of javascript code that fails silently - a typo in a variable name. It took me quite a long time to debug it manually.

It is part of a html web page, so I expected it (perhaps naively) to generate some message that would be reported in my apache error_log but it didn't.

How do you go about recording errors/warnings on your web servers that are related to js?

Is there a way to make it appear in your apache error_log?

Comment: You need to learn the difference between server-side and client-side

Comment: You can't. At least, not without explicitly writing your javascript to catch errors and send them to your server through Ajax. However, most (if not all) modern browsers have a Developer mode that helps you debug clientside issues.

Comment: @John Conde - true. My vision is blurry today. I'm using firebug to trace some things. Will study harder.

Answer (score 0):

As JavaScript is client side it will not show up in your Apache error_log.

What I'd suggest doing if you really want to see an "error log" related to your js, search out one of the many provided js error loggers or make your own if your feeling ambitious.

You can find a TON by doing a simple google search.

Good Luck!